# Issue with global variables with python and tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having an issue with the variables LoginChar and LoginRealm not being changed here:

```
LoginChar = StringVar
LoginRealm = StringVar
def Login(email,password):
    global LoginChar
    global LoginRealm
    login=auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email,password)
    test =db.get()
    for x in test.val():
        registeredList=db.child(x).child("registered").get()
        for y in registeredList.val():
            print(y)
            found_email=(db.child(x).child("registered").child(y).child("email").get().val())
            if found_email== email:

            Loggedinchar= y
            LoggedRealm = db.child(x).child("Realm").get().val()
            print("hello "+Loggedinchar+ "-"+LoggedRealm)
print("login success")
LoginChar = Loggedinchar
LoginRealm= LoggedRealm
print (LoginRealm)
loginFrame.pack_forget()
raise_frame(mainFrame)
```

And then when it is called when swapping frames it is not the changed values:

```
welcomeLabel = Label(mainFrame,text = LoginChar)
welcomeLabel.pack()
ExitMainFrameButton= Button(mainFrame,text="Exit",command=root.destroy)
ExitMainFrameButton.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning to the right variable.  Also, if you're using `StringVar` as intended, I don't think you need `global` at all since you can just `set` it.  Change:

```
LoginChar = StringVar
LoginRealm = StringVar
```

to:

```
LoginChar = StringVar()
LoginRealm = StringVar()
```

Remove the `global` declarations since you don't reassign these variables and you don't need to:

```
    global LoginChar
    global LoginRealm
```

Change:

```
            Loggedinchar= y
            LoggedRealm = db.child(x).child("Realm").get().val()
```

to:

```
            LoginChar.set(y)
            LoginRealm.set(db.child(x).child("Realm").get().val())
```

Now `LoginChar` and `LoginRealm` should contain the values that you set inside your function.

Comment: I tried that, the label is blank when i am declaring it as:
welcomeLabel = Label(mainFrame,text = LoginChar.get())

Comment: I don't really know tkinter, but try `welcomeLabel = Label(mainFrame, textvariable=LoginChar)`.  It seems like if you give it the `StringVar` rather than the `str` you get from `get()` it should be able to react to changes in the variable.  Otherwise you need to be very careful to create the label only after you've done `Login()` and it's not clear to me that you're doing that.